# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an abstract class below :

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test-service';

export abstract class DummyAbstract {

    constructor (
        private testService: TestService
    ) {

    }

    abstract thisisimp();
}
```

I have a child a class as below :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DummyAbstract } from './dummy-abstract';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThisChild extends DummyAbstract {
    thisisimp() {
        return 'text';
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to load the child class in some other service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ThisChild } from './this-child';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeOtherService {    
    constructor(private thisChild: ThisChild) {

    }
}
```

It throws the following error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8353)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:9057)
>       at inject (core.js:1403)
>       at injectArgs (core.js:1437)
>       at core.js:1491
>       at _callFactory (core.js:8431)
>       at *createProviderInstance (core.js:8389)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8364)
>       at NgModuleRef*.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:9057)
>       at inject (core.js:1403)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Angular Dependency Injection system only extracts/resolves dependency
>   for a class on which `Injectable` decorator is written. You've to handle other stuff by your own.

`DummyAbstract` constructor has constructor with `TestService` dependency, and when you extend using `ThisChild` provider, you haven't had passed `TestService` to the constructor of an `DummyAbstract`. Whenever you have such case you have to pass dependencies explicitly to the parent class using `super` method to call base class constructor.

```
export class ThisChild extends DummyAbstract {
    constructor(testService: TestService) { // no private or public
       super(testService); //calling base class constructor with dependency.
    }
    thisisimp() {
        return 'text';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since there is not much google search result for this problem I will provide my solution for it here (not related to this particular problem but with same error message).
So basically i get this problem as well:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
Nothing has been changed in a code before and after the error start to appears.
All i had to do was remove node_module folder, flush node cache and reinstall it and it started to work.
It was related to some angular material changes as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWaw, My issue exactly same what you have explain. When i reinstall npm then its resolved.

Comment: I just restarted the server, it worked for me. I got the same error--`(in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined at getInjectableDe....`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mock class object inside
 mockClassName  = TestBed(mockClassName):
Use real imported class object instead like below
mockClassName  =    TestBed(ClassName):