# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on an app that was going fine, all of a sudden I'm getting this error. Nothing has changed except that we were working on Angular 8 and another dev used Angular 9. After we merged code, this error started coming on randomly.

I deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm cache clean --force` and did a fresh npm install but still getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
    at getInjectableDef (core.js:361)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30377)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31578)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:734)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:744)
    at injectArgs (core.js:837)
    at core.js:16346
    at _callFactory (core.js:30486)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:30429)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30388)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

Comment: I think your answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53190932/12193298)

Comment: before reinstalling did you run `flush node cache`?

Comment: Make sure in constructor you are calling `super` method, if you are extending any class

Comment: @Jeroenouw and @Kenny my code has got nothing to do with calling `super` as I am not extending any class. Yes, I also flushed the node cache.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers that are already on SO, I am posting my findings as this might help someone else in the future.

One of the other devs deleted a service file from the app and checked the code in. We merged, everything was all good.

`ng build --prod` went fine

`ng serve` served the application fine

The app worked but this issue came up when we navigated to the component where this file was still referenced and getting injected in the constructor. Visual Studio 2019 gave no errors, hence it was a bit weird.

Probably a rare scenario as no one goes deleting files a lot but hope this helps others in case they encounter this scenario.